# "She's not been_____" or "She hasn't been_____"

Tags: british-english, negation

*Using the british-english tag because I'm wondering if it is commonly said this way or accepted as correct in the UK*

Is it grammatically correct to say, for example, "She's not been happy" instead of "She hasn't been happy"? Aren't they both ways of saying "She has not been happy"? I asked my mother and she seemed to think "She's not been____" is incorrect.

Comment: Both are correct, but "she's not..." is vanishingly rare in AmE - every time I've seen or heard the usage, it has originated with someone who normally speaks/writes BrE. I'd go so far as to say that if an American uses it, it's a deliberate affectation.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, I would say the first is more idiomatic.

Comment: I'm not actually British, but as a Land Rover owner and British car enthusiast in general, I hang around with a lot of Brits.  To me, both sound perfectly normal, but when I read them, I hear the first with a British accent and the second with an American one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's not been [something].
She hasn't been [something].

Both are the same. However, sometimes one might say one and at other times the other.  But I don't view them as BrE or AmE.

- She's not been herself recently.
- She hasn't been herself recently.

The first is ever so slightly higher in register. It's true, for instance, that I also hear it more frequently used in speech in British broadcast media/TV/series than in its AmE counterparts. [I know counterparts are usually people. Thank you.]

Answer (score 2):

[*She’s*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/she%27s) can be a contraction for “she is” or “she has.” Thus, both are grammatically correct.

As for British usage, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/she's) seems to hold that *she’s* is also a contraction for “she is” and “she has,” so I’d imagine it’s the same in both British and American usage.